# Extract elements of an array in a variable

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have defined such a variable in my logic App:

```
"Date": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Date",
                            "type": "Array",
                            "value": [
                                "2019-04-02",
                                "2019-04-03"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
```

in the next step in a for eachloop, I would like to use each Item in this array, hence I use this  code:

```
"body": {
           "CommitMode": "transactional",
           "MaxParallelism": 20,
           "Objects": [
            {
               "partition": "@concat('Table_',variables('Date'))",
               "table": "Table"
            }
           ],
           "RetryCount": 0,
           "Type": "Full"
            }
```

But after running my logic app in the output I see the following:

```
{
  "CommitMode": "transactional",
  "MaxParallelism": 20,
  "Objects": [
    {
      "partition": "Table_[\"2019-04-02\",\"2019-04-03\"]",
      "table": "Table"
    }
  ],
  "RetryCount": 0,
  "Type": "Full"
}
```

Do you have any idea, how can I extract each element of an array in logic app?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#join-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `For each` to concat the array, the below is my test.

[image]

And then response the result array.

[image]

Suppose this is what you want, hope this could help you.